# Counter only works once until browser restart

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a link in a html file.
When the link is clicked, an ajax request increments a counter in a file.
The target of the link is displayed in _blank.
The user opens the website from a citrix client.

Here i have the effect, that the counter gets only incremented, when the link is clicked for the first time. After that, the browser has to be restarted, to make the counter work again.
On my developement environment it is working well.
Do you have an idea, why this effect occurs? Can I somehow pretend that the browser was restarted?

link:

```
<p><a class="incCounter" onclick="incCounter('TL1');" href="page1.html" target="_blank">Dies ist Testlink1</a></p>
```

ajax request:

```
function incCounter(element)
{
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET","incCounter.php?e="+element,true);
  xhr.send();    
}
```

PHP file:

```
$element = $_GET["e"];
$filename = "clickcounter\\".$element.".txt";
$counter = 1;

if(file_exists($filename))
{
  //counter holen und inkrementieren
  $file = fopen($filename,"r");
  $counter = fgets($file);
  $counter++;
  fclose($file);
}

//datei ggfs. leeren und neuen counter schreiben
$file = fopen($filename,"w");
fwrite($file,$counter);
fclose($file);

return true;
```

Comment: how about if you store it in the cookies ?

Comment: it could be a caching issue.

Comment: It's not ajax request who increase counter but php. Your problem sims to be caching problem. Try to expand your request with a `salt`:

xhr.open("GET","incCounter.php?e="+element&rnd=' + Math.random(), true);

Comment: thank you so much @Daniel !!! I just added a salt to my request and it works.